# Error "Frame not in module." in Xamarin.Forms - Android project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, httpclient

Whenever it comes to this line, this error appears:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://mvalivros.azurewebsites.net/api/livros");
    var livros = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Livro>>(json);
    return livros;
}
```

A new tab appears in VS that says "Frame not in module."

It happens whenever the thread arrives at the `using` line.

[Frame not in module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOvba.png)

This is code complete...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LivrosApp.ApiLivros
{
    public static class Api
    {
        public static async Task<IList<Model.Livro>> GetAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://mvalivros.azurewebsites.net/api/livros");
                var livros = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Livro>>(json);
                return livros;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the Xamarin Visual Studio plugin? Also, do you still get the error if you remove all breakpoints?

Comment: so... yes and yes.. rsrs

Answer (score 2):

Annoying when this happens!! 
There is not one solution to this, have had this issue in past and few things you can try:

1. Change linking options -->Clean -->build
2. Change fast deployment --> build
3. Make sure mdb files are been generated and switch debug info
   generation to all/pdb files and rebuild
4. Exception settings -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions (should be ticked) If unticked tick the parent level so that everything below it is ticked
5. Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code
   (Ticked)
6. If none of them works then try stepping over (F10) instead of step
   into (F11)

Hopefully atleast one solution works!!

Comment: @DakshalRaijada I've tried all your suggestions and none of them has worked for me, do you have any other possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it worked for me after I make the following change.

Go to Debug -> Exceptions -> Uncheck Common Language Runtime Exception

Source where I get the solution from: [Debbuger doesn't work frame not in module.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27308/debugger-doesnt-work-frame-not-in-module)